# Chrome Os is damaged / installing ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome-os

I am sorry, that's not really a programming question. But I don't know where i have to ask my question. In fact, I have a computer with chrome OS. I have damaged the OS. ( I got the message : "google chrome OS is damaged" and i don't have any backup) It doesn 't really matter . My aim is to install ubuntu. So I was looking for a way to install it without recover chrome OS.  But everything I have found is about dual boot or recovery.. And ctrl + L is not working. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove chrome os completely can make use of OS-uninstaller or boot your computer with ubuntu, while selecting disk select something else and you can format the partition which has chrome and install ubuntu on it.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't say which model you're using exactly, so it's hard to give specific advice.

the scary recovery screen is shown by default even when in developer mode.  you have to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to tell it to boot from the disk anyways.  although this only supports CrOS formatted disks and not what Ubuntu would use by default.

if <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> doesn't work, it usually means your system doesn't support legacy boot, either because it's too old, or because you're using an ARM based chromebook.